# Actions on Google Fulfilment Issues

Tags: php, actions-on-google

When i test my app on the action simulator i dont receive a access token given from my Oauth2.0. (My Oauth2.0 Works prefectly when tested with Google Oauth Playground)
This is what i receive when user says 'turn on the living room lights'

```
Array
(
    [user] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1500637544218
            [permissions] => Array
                (
                )

            [locale] => en-US
        )

    [conversation] => Array
        (
            [conversation_id] => 1500637544218
            [type] => 1
        )

    [inputs] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [intent] => assistant.intent.action.MAIN
                    [raw_inputs] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [input_type] => 3
                                    [query] => tell automate to turn on the living room lights
                                    [annotation_sets] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [arguments] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => trigger_query
                                    [raw_text] => turn on the living room lights
                                    [text_value] => turn on the living room lights
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [surface] => Array
        (
            [capabilities] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT
                        )

                )

        )

    [device] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_in_sandbox] => 1
)
```

I figured in order to receive a access token i'd have to sign in to my Authorization End point but the actions simulator doesnt have that option, so i downloaded the Google Assistant app on my Andorid device ( Same Account as Developing) i went to home control and i couldn't see my app name listed. But when i ask the assistant (thru my phone this is) 'Talk to, ' it still returns "APP NAME isnt responding right now, try again soon"

## Actions.json

```
 {

  "accountLinking": {
    "clientId": "",          // SENSITIVE INFORMATION BLANK
    "clientSecret": "",       // SENSITIVE INFORMATION BLANK
    "grantType": "AUTH_CODE", 
  "authenticationUrl": "",      // SENSITIVE INFORMATION BLANK
  "accessTokenUrl": ""          // SENSITIVE INFORMATION BLANK


  },
  "actions": [{
        "description": "",
        "name": "MAIN",
        "fulfillment": {
            "conversationName": "PASS TEXT"
        },
        "intent": {
            "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
            "trigger": {
                "queryPatterns": [
                    "talk to APP NAME"
                ]
            }
        }
    }],

 "conversations": {
        "PASS TEXT": {
            "name": "PASS TEXT",
            "url": ""  // SENSITIVE INFORMATION BLANK
        }
    }
}
```

So my main two questions are, how do i resolve the "  isnt responding right now, try again soon"  issue and, how can my fulfilment end point receive access tokens? Becouse without the access tokens during testing i cannot further develop my app :(

Hope you can help me!

Comment: Asking the same question multiple times makes it more difficult to figure out where to answer it. Asking multiple questions in a single SO question compounds the problem.

Comment: Do u use Api.ai as intermediate?

Comment: So this is being developed using the Smart Home API?

Comment: No, im using Actions SDK. Im not using any smart home API nor google cloud functions. I just want RAW USER SPOKEN TEXT'S and ACCESS TOKEN to my fulfillment URL . I am taking care of everything from there using my own method :)

Comment: Ok... because you said you went to "Home Control" on the Home app. Please narrow this question to a single question and post your complete actions.json file (redacting sensitive information).

Comment: Okay, i updated the Question with the actions.json file :)